# Docker Access to Raspberry Pi GPIO Pins

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi2

When running Docker on the Raspberry Pi 2, how can we expose the GPIO pins to the Docker container?

Answer (score 134):

On a Linux host, there are three possible ways to get access to the GPIO pins from within a Docker container.

### 1. Running Docker with the "--privileged" option

Starting a container like this will give the container full access to the host's devices, including GPIO:

```
$ docker run --privileged -d whatever
```

Check the [Docker documentation on this option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities). It might not be the best choice depending on how tight your security requirements are.

### 2. Adding the /dev/gpiomem device

Rather than exposing all of the host's devices to the container, you can be specific and only expose the /dev/gpiomem device to the container at runtime. Be aware that this device needs kernel driver support within the host's Linux distribution. Recent releases of Raspbian should have this. Your mileage with other distributions may vary.

```
$ docker run --device /dev/gpiomem -d whatever
```

### 3. Using the sysfs filesystem on the host

The Pi's GPIO is represented within the host's file system underneath /sys/class/gpio. This can be accessed with user privileges via the virtual files in that file system. Use Docker volumes to expose this to your container:

```
$ docker run -v /sys:/sys -d whatever
```

Mind that using sysfs for GPIO is probably going to be slower than the device approach.

#### GPIO libraries

Which of these three approaches fits your needs will also depend on the libraries you are using when accessing GPIO. Not all libraries support all three of these options.

Comment: The new docker swarm mode using version 3 of docker-compose.yml doesn't allow either the privileged option or the device option.  I'm using RPi.GPIO python library within my docker container.  The sysfs method doesn't seem to work with that library.  Anyone know of any other options?

Comment: I am using libgpiod - for that I had to map `/dev/gpiochip0` (or using privileged mode also worked).

Answer (score 7):

You would probably use `docker volumes` to expose the `sysfs` interface.  For example, something like:

```
docker run -v /sys:/sys fedora bash
```

This would expose `/sys` on the host as `/sys` inside the container, and you would have access to the `/sys/class/gpio` hierarchy.

If you were using code that access the GPIO pins without using the `sysfs` interface you would need to expose whatever device node it is using inside the container, possibly with something like the `--device` argument to `docker run`.

Answer (score 6):

I would use this image: https://github.com/acencini/rpi-python-serial-wiringpi, as a base image. Here you can easily access with python. Or you can decide to download node onto the image and use these two npm libraries to access through javascript

https://github.com/bryan-m-hughes/raspi --
https://github.com/bryan-m-hughes/raspi-gpio

The base for the whole thing is wiringPi as you can see in the Dockerfile, and that you have to run this command when you run up the image the first time:

```
docker run --device /dev/ttyAMA0:/dev/ttyAMA0 --device /dev/mem:/dev/mem --privileged -ti acencini/rpi-python-serial-wiringpi /bin/bash
```

Whats important here is that you open up dev ports and mem for wiringPi to access it. Privileged access to /dev/mem is required by wiringPi.

Comment: I was able to get wiringpi working in a container by using `--device /dev/gpiomem:/dev/gpiomem` and **without** using `--privileged`.

Answer (score 2):

In application with [onoff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onoff) on raspberry pi 3B+, mounting `/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio` and `/sys/class/gpio` is enough.

```
docker run \
  -v /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio:/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio \
  -v /sys/class/gpio:/sys/class/gpio \
  ...
```

I am still looking for better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Azure IoT Edge and docker on it then following steps will help you out.

1. Add property **"Privileged" : true** into file *deployment.template.json*

   ```
       "modules": {
        "gpio": {
         "version": "1.0",
         "type": "docker",
         "status": "running",
         "restartPolicy": "always",
         "settings": {
           "image": "${MODULES.gpio}",
           "createOptions": {
            "HostConfig": {
              "Privileged": true
           }
         }
       }
     },
   ```
2. Comment out **moduleuser** creation in file *Dockerfile.arm32v7*. Moduleuser doesnt have enough permissions and therefore it ignores Privileged:true option. Without it docker will run in root privileges.

```
    # RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash moduleuser
    # USER moduleuser
```

3. Add reference to **System.Device.Gpio**.
   It is currenlty in prerelease but it works. https://github.com/dotnet/iot