# Is it possible to use RPi.GPIO library in docker？

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi4

I used the official docker image of flask. And installed the rpi.gpio library in the container

```
pip install rpi.gpio
```

It's succeeded:

```
root@e31ba5814e51:/app# pip install rpi.gpio
Collecting rpi.gpio
  Downloading RPi.GPIO-0.7.0.tar.gz (30 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: rpi.gpio
  Building wheel for rpi.gpio (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for rpi.gpio: filename=RPi.GPIO-0.7.0-cp39-cp39-linux_armv7l.whl size=68495 sha256=0c2c43867c304f2ca21da6cc923b13e4ba22a60a77f7309be72d449c51c669db
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/09/be/52/39b324bfaf72ab9a47e81519994b2be5ddae1e99ddacd7a18e
Successfully built rpi.gpio
Installing collected packages: rpi.gpio
Successfully installed rpi.gpio-0.7.0
```

But it prompted the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/hello/app2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/RPi/GPIO/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from RPi._GPIO import *
RuntimeError: This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!
```

I tried the method in this link, but it didn't work:
[Docker Access to Raspberry Pi GPIO Pins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059784/docker-access-to-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins)

I want to know if this can be done, and if so, how to proceed.

Comment: Are you sure that the base image you are using is for armhf?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is! To extend the answer of Ari M.:

It's more safe to run

```
$ docker run --device /dev/gpiomem -d whatever
```

as it avoids full privileged host access.

It's also necessary to build your image on RaspberyPi.

This answers showed me the way:

[How to enable wiringpi GPIO control inside a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094979/how-to-enable-wiringpi-gpio-control-inside-a-docker-container)

[Docker Access to Raspberry Pi GPIO Pins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059784/docker-access-to-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you're running Docker container as "privileged" like so:

```
docker run --privileged -it debian:latest
```

Also, double check that you're running an image that is meant to run on your processor.

For example, if you try to run "debian:latest" on your Raspberry Pi 4 it will actually pull "arm32v7/debian:latest".