# IoT Edge on Raspberry Pi - using GPIO Driver

Tags: iot, azure-iot-edge

Using VScode I have taken the led-blink sample code from https://github.com/dotnet/iot and placed it into an IotEdge module template with the intention of having it run in a container on IoT edge and then use device twin properties to modify some of the variables on the fly through IoT Hub. After loading the module it starts ups but the logs show the following error

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Error 2 initializing the Gpio driver.
   at System.Device.Gpio.Drivers.RaspberryPi3LinuxDriver.Initialize()
   at System.Device.Gpio.Drivers.RaspberryPi3LinuxDriver.OpenPin(Int32 pinNumber)
   at System.Device.Gpio.Drivers.RaspberryPi3Driver.OpenPin(Int32 pinNumber)
   at System.Device.Gpio.GpioController.OpenPin(Int32 pinNumber)
   at edgetestmodule20sep.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/Program.cs:line 29
```

Can anyone advise what is going on here and what a possible solution might be?

Comment: See this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059784/docker-access-to-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins One of the later ones specifically deals with IoT Edge on Pi. Essentially your container does not have the privileges.

Comment: thanks @MarkRadbourne, I came across the same last night and (after figuring out how to actually implement it) it has solved the problem

Comment: @rareg3636 glad you are unblocked :). Please mark below as answer to help others as well. Thanks!