# Access Raspberry Pi modules from Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to access Raspberry Pi from a Spring Boot Application (possibly running on docker container on that RPi), for example using Pi4J or do I need to create an itermediary app that would communicate with the spring boot app?

For context - I need to create a web application that would allow remote control of several DC Engines.

Comment: Define What you mean by access? Give an example/use-case.

Comment: you could create a local web service on the pi and only allow connections from localhost. Call the local web services to control the pins from the spring boot application via REST

Comment: @Yogesh_D I have given the context - I need to control DC engines via REST API

Comment: @codebrane so it is possible to control the pins from within the spring boot app, right?

Comment: Please check this example which is a combination of heading + spring + pi4j https://foojay.io/today/blink-a-led-on-raspberry-pi-with-vaadin/ that shows you can indeed use spring with pi4j on the raspberry pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand you want to do is:

Have a Web/Rest Application running on a Pi that allows you to control things like GPIO, PWN, I2C functionality on the Pi.
This is possible using pi4j. You can find the details at https://pi4j.com/.

This library will allow you to control things like [GPIO](https://pi4j.com/documentation/io-examples/digital-output/), [PWM](https://pi4j.com/documentation/io-examples/pwm/), [Servos](https://pi4j.com/documentation/device-examples/components/servo/).

Do note that I am not sure of the intricacies of running this pi4j based application inside a docker container as it requires access to native system which will be abstracted out in the docker env.

I would suggest building a regular app running natively and then work on moving it into a docker image.

Note: By DC Engine I am assuming you mean DC Motors.

Answer (score 1):

Using Pi4J you could access the GPIO pins directly, [example here](https://pi4j.com/getting-started/minimal-example-application/). You could [build Pi4J in a docker container](https://pi4j.com/architecture/about-the-code/build-instructions/#building-with-docker) and put the Spring boot app in the same container and [allow the container to access the GPIO pins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30059784/4294399).

That would be the backend implementation. For the the client facing implementation you could create a REST API in the Spring boot app, e.g.:

```
GET https://your.rpi.com/engine/{name}/
```

which returns JSON status of engine
e.g.

```
https://your.rpi.com/engine/airconditioning/
```

returns:

{
"status": "running"
}

then:

```
PUT https://your.rpi.com/engine/airconditioning/start
PUT https://your.rpi.com/engine/airconditioning/stop
```

although the above are not strictly REST. They are RPC.

Or PUT to a control endpoint:

```
PUT https://your.rpi.com/engine/airconditioning/
```

with the content:

```
{
  "command": "start|stop"
}
```

PUT would be a better choice as POST is used in REST to create a new resource. You would be changing the status of an existing resource, i.e. an engine.

The code that implements the endpoints e.g.

```
https://your.rpi.com/engine/{name}/
```

would be where the Pi4J integration was implemented.