# can't access /dev/mem in a docker container

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, zynq

I'm trying to read a memory mapped register on a Zynq running linux. I'm using python but I'm pretty sure my issue is system related. Outside of docker I can open /dev/mem and mmap the appropriate segment but when I try and access it using docker-compose I'm getting permission issues.
I've added the container user to kmem and I've tried running the container as root.
I've run with and without privileged: true
I've used volume and device mounts (volumes: "/dev/mem:/dev/mem" and devices: "/dev/mem"),

I'm using O_RDONLY|O_SYNC to open /dev/mem and MAP_SHARED, PROT_READ to mmap it but I always get a permission denied. Even dd if=/dev/mem skip=0x80100000 count=16 gives a permission issue.
I'm running containerd as root.

There must be some permission issue I'm missing, any ideas?

Comment: Please add a complete [mcve] that demonstrates what you are doing.  A full program is much clearer than any amount of explanation.

Comment: This command works : `docker run -v /dev/mem:/dev/mem --privileged ubuntu dd if=/dev/mem skip=00x80100000 count=16 of=/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

look at this :[Docker Access to Raspberry Pi GPIO Pins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059784/docker-access-to-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins)
access /dev/mem is same to access gpio sysfs:

1. Running Docker with the "--privileged" option

   Starting a container like this will give the container full access to the host's devices, including /dev/mem:

   $ docker run --privileged -d whatever

   Check the Docker documentation(https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) on this option. It might not be the best choice depending on how tight your security requirements are.
2. Only assign  /dev/mem device to docker by "--device" option

   Rather than exposing all of the host's devices to the container, you can be specific and only expose the /dev/mem device to the container at runtime.

   $ docker run --device /dev/mem -d whatever